# How to match three or more items

Tags: powershell

Can't seem to get my head around this. I want to compare three (or more) items - example below - how can I get it to state true? If I do two items it works fine

```
$a = 2
$b = 2
$c = 2

$a -match $b -match $c
False
```

Looking at `$Matches` it only contains two items. I tried brackets around `$a` and `$b` but still get the same thing - it keeps on only looking at the first two and ignores the third.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $Matches

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
0                              2
```

Comment: Your snippet is not working as expected because comparing two variables in the first place, gives you true or false, that means 1 or 0. So, if you'll compare 1 or 0 with 2, it will obviously give false.

Comment: @PrernaJain: Not strictly true if the left operand is an array.

Comment: Yea thanks @Joey . I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your snippet is not working as expected because :

*comparing two variables in the first place, gives you true or false,
 that means 1 or 0. So, if you'll compare 1 or 0 with 2, it will obviously give false.*

In simple terms :

> $a -match $b -match $c equates to :

```
$a -match $b 
true

true -match $c
false
```

So, as Martin has answered, you need to do it this way if you need it for regular expression comparison:

```
$a -match $b -and $a -match $c
true
```

But since you are comparing values so you need to use, ***-eq*** .

Answer (score 1):

```
$a -match $b -match $c
```

actually results in the following:

```
[bool] $r1 = $a -match $b
[string] $r1 -match $c
```

Which is probably not what you want. In fact, I'm quite unsure *what* you actually want. The `-match` operator performs a regex match of the left operand. Do you perhaps mean something like

```
$a -eq $b -and $b -eq $c
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You need to *combine your checks* using `-and`. Also use `-eq` (equals) here:

```
$a -eq $b -and $a -eq $c
```